# Do LiveCards provide precise life cycle methods the way activities do?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

In my application I used TimelineManager to display a LiveCard. I want to invoke a UDP request when the app is visible to user. I case if Activity, onResume() invoked automatically, but I am doing it in Service.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in your app that depends on the card  being looked at by the user? By the way, you may need to handle the case where the card is "visible" but the user has deactivated the display (e.g. by moving head up to turn off display). That pause is a bit more complicated to detect.  (No code to offer there yet, so that is why this is only a comment.)

Comment: Erst - When using an activity the lifecycle is precise, no matter how you stop an activity, the onPause and onStop methods are called, I have tested this with a swipe down, a head gesture, and a 10 second timeout.  The only way to not have these fire is if there is an uncaught exception and all bets are off.

Sujay - Services have different lifecycles than activities, try the bindService technique described here, I have not tested this, but I think it will work for you - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle